# Is there a cross-browser way to precisely vertically size an inline element?

Tags: css, cross-browser

Imagine CSS like:

```
.x {
  background: blue none;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

and HTML like:

```
<div>Words and <span class="x">decorated</span> words</div>
```

The height of the span reading 'decorated' is going to vary wildly between different browsers, and between different OSes running otherwise the same browser.

Is there any way to make it be the same height?

(I don’t want to move to inline-block or sacrifice the text using exactly the same baseline.)

Answer (score 1):

My experience with avoiding of different height is setting exact *line-height* and *font-size*

Comment: I am doing so. (I even made sure to try setting them on the inline elements and not just on their container, even though these properties are inherited.) But it’s not enough, sadly. At 24px/36px, there is as much as 9px (!) difference in element height between browsers (actually, 8px difference between Firefox on Linux and on Mac!)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there is something else causing your problem.  I just tried a basic html5 document with the snippits from your question and compared the alignment on Windows with Chrome, Safari, FF & IE.  They all rendered exactly the same except for IE9 which had a 1px gap above the span only.

Granted Mac renders fonts differently from Windows, and I didn't test on linux or mac, but 9px!!!???  Here are some things I'd investigate:

First, try a basic test file if you are working in a larger project, this will limit your variables.

Second, try setting explicit fonts and ensuring they exist on all of your test machines - perhaps linux is falling back to a different font.

Third, make sure you are not zoomed in or using a custom font size browser setting on any of the browsers (I ran into this one a while back where somehow my IE was set to 105% zoom.)

Finally, if all of that fails, you might want to try using a web font (@font-face) and see if that renders more strictly.

---

Edit:

In lieu of the new information in your comment, another strategy would be to use JavaScript to inspect the rendered heights of some off-screen elements and then programmatically adjust styles accordingly.  You'll probably get a huge FOUC, but you can use a whiteout div to minimize the shift.

Comment: Definitely different fonts are part of the problem, yes. But of course “make sure [the fonts] exist on all of your test machines,” while a valid debugging step, is not a real-world solution as my users won’t all have the same fonts. Nor do I want to use a web font for body text :)

Comment: Sounds like you have two incompatible requirements - you don't want to use cross-platform fonts and you don't want to use a web-font to ensure cross-platform consistency.  Is there a reason you're against web-fonts for body text?  Unlike approaches like cufon, font-face declarations do not really impact performance when used heavily for body text.  And after optimization their initial download footprint is pretty reasonable even over 3g.  Google, even offers free hosted fonts which makes the initial download asynchronous.